# Can I run TFS automated builds using both VS2010 and VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

We currently use TFS 2010 and have numerous build definitions for our various version of our software.   We want to use VS2012 for our next version(still using TFS 2010) so is it possible to have both versions of VS on a build controller and will the build process know which version of VS to use or will we need one build controller for VS2010 and one for VS2012?  Also I have custom build templates will that present any issues?  Then what happens when we upgrade to TFS 2012?  will we be able to run automated builds using both VS2010 and VS2012??

Answer (score 1):

In general - yes. Actually Visual Studio doesn't build anything. It's the underlying **MSBuild** engine that handles the build tasks.

Furthermore, you can setup a build machine without Visual Studio at all, provided that your project don't hold direct references to Visual Studio references paths (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies`). If there are such references you can copy them to your 3rd party\lib directory in the source control and have the projects refer to that directory as file references.

Other notes:

- But Visual Studio will hardly be your biggest hindrance. It's
  multi-targeting .NET that will require some extra caffeine :)
- The build templates will work as long as you satisfy their custom
  references (GAC can used for that matter)
- A build controller can be registered with one server at a time
- Use a build server for each target framework\VS version